# Question on a paper of Schoen and Yau

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am trying to understand the paper "[Conformally flat manifolds, Kleinian groups and scalar curvature](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01393992)" by Schoen and Yau. In P.56, it says:

> This implies that $\partial M$ has a zero $q$-capacity, and a standard result [AM] then implies that the Hausdorff dimension of $\partial M$ is less than or equal to $n-q$...

The reference [AM] refers to the paper "[Bessel potentials, inclusion relations among classes of exceptional sets](http://www.iumj.indiana.edu/oai/1973/22/22074/22074.xml)" of Adam and Meyers published in *Indiana Univ. Math. J.* (1973) **22**, 876-905. I tried to read the paper of Adam and Meyers, but I did not know which theorem Schoen and Yau referred to. Also, I wonder if there are some easy ways to prove that the above claim of Schoen-Yau, since it was claimed to be standard.

Comment: In case someone is still interested in this six years later, you can find the answer in the book of Evans and Gariepy called `Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions'. The section of the book on capacity discusses this point. To be precise, in my edition of the book this is Theorem 4 of Section 4.7, on page 156. (I'll admit I haven't read the paper of Adam and Meyers.)